# Saving dataframe to file using multichar delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, delimiter

This is my dataframe looks,

```
>df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':["a","b","c"],'col2':["tg","jhu","uyg"]})
>df
  col1 col2
0    a   tg
1    b  jhu
2    c  uyg
```

I want to save this dataframe using mutlichar delimiter |@| and need to quote all values, so i am using below statement.

```
df.to_csv('out.txt',sep='|@|',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Am getting error like this.

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

Desired output is this,

```
"col1"|@|"col2"
"a"|@|"tg"
"b"|@|"jhu"
"c"|@|"uyg"
```

can someone help with the logic that can be helpful to achieve this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a limitation by the `csv` module, not `pandas`'s. Using more than 1 character for column separation is really strange. May I ask what is your purpose in doing that?

Comment: Because my columns are free text fields and it contains all special charcters

Comment: There is an escape mechanism for that, even if you use comma as the separation character

Comment: you mean placing escape character before special charcters?